# SQLDeveloper Does not start in debug mode

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run the `sql developer`  in debug mode and i get the following error. I turned off the firewall on the windows machine. (I think my antiviruses firewall is still turned on, i'm not sure if it causing)

```
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', '51814' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What could be causing this issue?

Another Question, i'm new to sql develper+PL/SQL development. I have a lot of `dbms_output.put_line(string)`  statements  in the pl/sql code. I need to see what it is printing, does this show up in the sql developer logs/console only if the debugger is turned on?

**Edit:**
If debugger is not required to print the `dbms_output.putline` statements then how do i run the already existing methods in a package and make it print in the dbms output console?

Answer (score 2):

To see the results of your DBMS_OUTPUT calls, you need to enable DBMS_OUTPUT in the client.  In SQL Developer, select View -> Dbms Output.  In the Dbms Output pane, click the green plus sign to enable output processing.

(The DBMS_OUTPUT calls in PL/SQL simply put data into a buffer in memory on the server.  In order to actually see the output, the client needs to be told to fetch and display the contents  of this buffer.)

Comment: Should I enable debug somewhere in the existing pl/sql package body?

Comment: @Zeus - No.  You just need to enable it in the client.  Unless for some reason your code is calling `dbms_output.disable` or is calling `dbms_output.enable` with a buffer size that is too small.

Comment: could you please point me to the menu / location where we enable it on the client?